# jquery selector of next element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I try to get a next element but it doesn't work.

Here is the list of elements:

[image]

**What I tried :**

I can get the current div selected :

```
let cb='BBBBDBJLBDFEFGG';
$("div").find(`[data-codebarre='${cb}']`)   // OKAY
```

To get the first element:

```
var selector = $('.items-body-content[data-codebarre]').first();  //OKAY
```

Now I would like to get the next div following the div selected

I tried many things (including next() closest() find() etc) but I didn't find a solution)

**Result :**

No element found.

If I try :

```
$('.items-body-content[data-codebarre]').eq(1)
```

then I get the second div existing with class "items-body-content" // KO

How to get the div AFTER the div in blue ?

Comment: Hi! Please post code, error messages, markup, etc. **as text**, not as a *picture* of text. Why: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/157247

Comment: Have you tried `$('.items-body-content[data-codebarre]').eq(1)`?

Comment: *"I tried many things (including next() closest() find() etc) but I didn't find a solution)"* ][`next`](http://api.jquery.com/next) is literally the solution, specifically: ```let cb='BBBBDBJLBDFEFGG'; $("div").find(`[data-codebarre='${cb}']`).next();```. Please show us the code that didn't work and say specifically what happened that wasn't what you expected.

Comment: "what happenened" => no selector are found

Comment: @iota the selector is the second in the list, but I would like to get the div after the div in blue

Comment: *"No selector are found"* doesn't make any sense. Do you mean no *elements* are found? Selectors are strings. If that's what you're saying, I can't see why that would be from the above. Please update your question with a runnable [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button); [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/).

Comment: (Another way to do it is ```let cb='BBBBDBJLBDFEFGG'; $("div").find(`[data-codebarre='${cb}'] + *`);```)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, this is the answer

Comment: As long as you did `.next()` and not `.next(selector)` you'll be ok - but we don't know what you did/didn't do

Comment: As noted above - if you included html, then we could provide you a working sample in seconds... but I, for one, won't be typing in your HTML.

Comment: to be clear: `$("div.items-body").find(\`[data-codebarre='${cb}'\`).next()`

Answer (score 0):

Because you did not provide a html to reproduce your problem, I made some assumptions.

I think this is what you want:

```
var selector = $('.items-body-content[data-codebarre]').first().next();
document.write("The next div innertext is: "+selector[0].innerText)
```

I assumed the following html:

```
<div class="items-body-content" data-codebarre="BBBBDBJLBDFEFGG">test</div>
<div class="x" data-codebarre="next">test2</div>
```

The second div should be selected. This div does not have the "items-body-content" class, like the one you use in the selector.

So the idea being that the selector (the $() ) returns a list of items. We get the first item. Then we want the next "thing" from the html. next() gives that to us.

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/198ebf4j/

Edit: Or do you actually want the next *div* after the selected div?:

```
var selector = $('.items-body-content[data-codebarre] + div').first();
document.write("The next div innertext is: "+selector[0].innerText)
```

JsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6tqu9o0k/